# Convert oOo to Brainfuck and vice-versa

Tags: haskell, brainfuck

This program was inspired by a [Code Golf challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/74402/translate-ooo-code#74405) that I wanted to do properly. It simply converts oOo to Brainfuck and vice-versa.

The oOo language basically uses UPPER / lower case information in groups of 3 to encode a Brainfuck program. For further info see the [Esolang wiki page of oOo](https://esolangs.org/wiki/OOo_CODE).

The main problem with this code is that I feel like there is repetition in the encode / decode functions because they seem to contain similar type of information. I am also worried that I did not declare any types as Haskell is type-centric.

```
import qualified Data.Char as C
import qualified Data.List.Split as L
import qualified Test.QuickCheck as Q
import qualified Test.HUnit as T

oToBrain :: String -> String
oToBrain = map chunkToBrain . L.chunksOf 3 . filter isAlphabetic

brainToO :: String -> String
brainToO = concatMap singleCharToO

singleCharToO :: Char -> String
singleCharToO x = case x of
  '>' -> "ooo"
  '<' -> "ooO"
  '[' -> "oOo"
  ']' -> "oOO"
  '-' -> "Ooo"
  '+' -> "OoO"
  '.' -> "OOo"
  ',' -> "OOO"
  _ -> ""

isAlphabetic :: Char -> Bool
isAlphabetic = (`elem` ['a'..'z']) . C.toLower

chunkToBrain :: String -> Char
chunkToBrain [a, b, c] = case  (C.isUpper a, C.isUpper b, C.isUpper c) of
  (False, False, False) -> '>'
  (False, False, True ) -> '<'
  (False, True,  False) -> '['
  (False, True,  True ) -> ']'
  (True,  False, False) -> '-'
  (True,  False, True ) -> '+'
  (True,  True,  False) -> '.'
  (True,  True,  True ) -> ','
chunkToBrain _ = error "`oOo` chunks can only be 3 chars long" 

brainChars :: Q.Gen String
brainChars = Q.listOf (Q.elements "<>[]+-.,")

doubleConversionIsId :: Q.Property
doubleConversionIsId = Q.forAll brainChars $ \x -> x == (oToBrain . brainToO) x

main = do
  T.assertEqual "Wiki example" ",[>,]<[.<]+" (oToBrain "PROgRam reVERsES giVeN iNPut sEqUENcE")
  Q.quickCheck doubleConversionIsId
```

Comment: Nice of you to post here rather than [some other site](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/74402).

Comment: @200_success Well, I had not intention to golf it, so here I am.

Comment: found some time to edit my answer

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> import qualified Data.Char as C
> import qualified Data.List.Split as L
> import qualified Test.QuickCheck as Q
> import qualified Test.HUnit as T
> ```

The qualified import here is good, but your module header is missing. Since there is no documentation you don't want to export some functions, for example the partial `chunkToBrain`.

> ```
> oToBrain :: String -> String
> oToBrain = map chunkToBrain . L.chunksOf 3 . filter isAlphabetic
> ```

While this might seem correct, the combination of `chunkToBrain` and `L.chunksOf` doesn't end well. According to [esolangs](https://esolangs.org/wiki/OOo_CODE), oOo code may have a non-divisible number of letters. The remaining ones are discarded. More on that later on `chunkToBrain`.

`brainToO` is fine, but `isAlphabetic` isn't, as `elem ['a'..'z']` is `C.isAsciiLower`:

```
isAlphabetic = C.isAsciiLower . C.toLower
```

We will now take a look at your source of duplication, `singleCharToO` and `chunkToBrain`. Both suffer from somewhat the same problem: you need to define the map from Brainfuck instructions to oOo instructions and vice-versa. So let's define them:

```
oOoCode :: [String]
oOoCode = ["ooo", "ooO", "oOo", "oOO", "Ooo", "OoO", "OOo", "OOO"]

bfCode :: [Char]
bfCode  = [  '>',   '<',   '[',   ']',   '-',   '+',   '.',   ',']

bf2oOo :: [(Char, String)]
bf2oOo = zip bfCode oOoCode

oOo2bf :: [(String, Char)]
oOo2bf = zip oOoCode bfCode
```

Now `singleCharToO` is

```
singleCharToO x = fromMaybe "" (lookup x bf2oOo)
```

where `fromMaybe` is from `Data.Maybe`. You can use `maybe "" id` instead if you don't want to import another module.

Now to `chunkToBrain`. We will write a single helper beforehand:

```
toO :: Char -> Char
toO x = if C.isUpper x then 'O' else 'o'
```

I think you can already guess what happens next:

```
chunkToBrain :: String -> Maybe Char
chunkToBrain xs = lookup xs oOo2bf
```

You can of course use other data structures with better asymptotic complexity, but since there are only \$2^3\$ instructions this might be an overkill and should be benchmarked.

But wait a minute: the return type has changed. That's because the text is allowed to have superflous characters. `"oOoOO"` and `"oOo"` are the same programs in oOo. This leads to a slight change in `oToBrain`:

```
oToBrain = mapMaybe chunkToBrain . L.chunksOf 3 . filter isAlphabetic
```

Where `mapMaybe` is again a function from `Data.Maybe`, that discards `Nothing` from the list. This version of `oToBrain` has the right semantics, it doesn't throw an error.

Last but not least, your tests are sufficient for this code, although you should include tests that have oOo programs with a length that's not divisible by three.

---

> I am also worried that I did not declare any types as Haskell is type-centric.

At this point, we're slowly drifting out of the simple exercise and completely into parsing, pretty printing and (possibly) interpretation. What's a fitting data type for your code? No, let's have a look at the greater picture. What's a fitting data type for a Brainfuck or oOo program?

```
type Program = [Instruction]
data Instruction = IncVal | DecVal
                 | IncPos | DecPos
                 | Put    | Get
                 | Repeat Program
```

You'll notice that this will only allow syntactic correct programs, e.g. those that have the right pairings of `[` and `]`. You can use `StartRepeat` and `EndRepeat` instead, but that could make evaluation tricky.

You can then define two parsers:

```
-- or any other type with an erroneous state    
oOoParser :: String -> Either String Program 
bfParser  :: String -> Either String Program
```

Getting code again can be done similar to your previous code, although you need to apply the codegen recursively for `Repeat`.

```
toBF  :: Program -> String
tooOo :: Program -> String
```

The conversions can be defined in terms of the other four:

```
bf2oOo, oOo2bf :: String -> Either String String
bf2oOo = fmap toBF . oOoParser
oOo2bf = fmap tooOo . bfParser
```

This approach also allows you to define your own evaluation function without worrying about the loops:

```
eval :: Program -> String -> String
eval prog input = ...
```

But that's out of scope of this answer. Note that `eval` gets harder if you don't use the recursive `Repeat` variant, but parsing gets easier (and vice-versa).

Answer (score 1):

First of all - your solution is quite readable, and you have already pointed out the features it lacks: types and repeated code.

I chose to put this in a library/module to show that if you want to hide certain pieces of your implementation this would be the way to go.

```
module Languages ( Brainfuck
                 , OoO
                 , mkBrainFuck
                 , mkOoO
                 , encode
                 , decode)
                 where
```

both types `Brainfuck` and `OoO` are just synonyms one for `String`, the other for `[String]`, I chose the latter to have triplets of characters as the basic encoding entity in `OoO`. But with the constructors hidden the user of this library doesn't even have to know about this, for him/her this is just something "like a String", as it can be created from a `String` by using `mk...`.

This also provides a basic type of documentatation - which would be automatically produced by `haddock` (the documentation tool).

```
import Data.List.Split as L
import Data.Char (isLower,isLetter)
import qualified Data.Map.Lazy as M
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)

newtype Brainfuck = Brainfuck String deriving (Show, Eq)
newtype OoO = OoO [String] deriving (Eq)
instance Show OoO where
    show (OoO strs) = unwords strs
```

this handcrafted `Show` instance just joins the triplets with a space for better readability.

```
type OoOExp = String
type BrainfuckExp = Char

oooExps :: [OoOExp]
oooExps = [ "ooo", "ooO", "oOo", "oOO", "Ooo", "OoO", "OOo", "OOO"]

bfExps :: [BrainfuckExp]
bfExps = ['>', '<', '[', ']', '-', '+', '.', ',']
```

these two lists will be used as the "translation table" and for sanity checks in the "smart" constructors.

```
encode :: OoO -> Brainfuck
encode (OoO o)= Brainfuck $ map convert o
  where msg = "Error: encountered invalid OoO expression: "
        convert :: OoOExp -> BrainfuckExp
        convert x = fromMaybe (error $ msg ++ show x) $
                             M.lookup x table
        table = M.fromList $ zip oooExps bfExps
```

In my opinion `encode` is a better name than `oToBrain` because on the one side it captures its task in a simple word and the type says what it encodes.

The encoding itself is rather straightforward, what might be a bit interesting to the newcomer is the convert function - we use a lookup table of `Map OoOExp BrainfuckExp` - which is the functional equivalent of a "hashmap" or associative array. Note that this lookup yields a `Maybe value` as the searched expression (potentially) can't be found.

I still chose to throw an `error` because I take care by construction that no invalid `OoO` are possible input values.

```
decode :: Brainfuck -> OoO
decode (Brainfuck bf )= OoO $ map convert bf
  where msg = "Error: encountered invalid Brainfuck expression: "
        convert :: BrainfuckExp -> OoOExp
        convert x = fromMaybe (error $ msg ++ show x) $
                              M.lookup x table
        table = M.fromList $ zip bfExps oooExps
```

`decode` is just the same thing in reverse, which is still a duplicate code, one could abstract this a bit further by introducing a `typeclass` for convertible classes. I chose to just reverse the arguments for the lookup table and changing the error message accordingly.

`mk...` are the heart of this piece - they construct types from `Strings` in a "smart" way, i.e. for `mkOoO` it checks if the chunks have proper size, getting rid of non letter characters and normalizing letters to 'o's and 'O's, and for `mkBrainFuck` we check just for the elements of the `String` being one of the valid characters.

Both functions yield a `Nothing` in the case of failure and `Just value` in the case of success, which can then be used with `fmap` or `<$>` to use `encode`/`decode` for conversion.

In a real world example I would use a proper parser like `parsec` which makes better error messages.

```
mkOoO :: String -> Maybe OoO
--here I would really use a parser to get rid of such things as comments
mkOoO str = checkOoOs $ chunksOf 3 $ [if isLower x then 'o' else 'O'| x <- str,isLetter x]
  where checkOoOs ooos = if all (`elem` oooExps) ooos
                            then Just $ OoO ooos
                            else Nothing

mkBrainFuck :: String -> Maybe Brainfuck
--here I would really use a parser to get rid of such things as comments
mkBrainFuck str = if all (`elem` bfExps) str
                     then Just $ Brainfuck str
                     else Nothing
```